# Visual Studio: ¿Se permite redistribuir fonts de terceros, hay problemas?

Tags: visual-studio, fuentes

Estoy creando un proyecto con fonts personalizadas (por las licencias de las fonts no hay que preocuparse, permiten uso comercial y redistribución).

El problema es que, en los terminos (https://www.visualstudio.com/es/license-terms/mlt553321/) menciona:
**"c. Componentes de fuente.** Mientras se ejecuta el software, puede utilizar sus fuentes para mostrar e imprimir contenido. Solamente puede (i) incrustar fuentes en el contenido, de acuerdo con lo que permitan las restricciones de incrustación de fuentes"...

El punto es que NO quiero incrustarla como tal, quiero vincularla, poner ese tipo de letra en los textos de mi programa y con un creador de SETUP (inno setup por ejemplo) quiero hacer que se instalen las fuentes en el sistema, de esta forma al ya estar instaladas y al abrir mi programa, se vea tal como lo creé. Lo anteriormente mencionado funciona, pero **¿Se me permite hacer esto? ¿O los términos estan hablando únicamente de las fonts del mismo Microsoft y deja fuera a las fonts de terceros?**

Comment: Se refiere a que las fuentes de terceros tienen sus propias restricciones de uso, es decir, si la fuente que utilizas actualmente no puede ser redistribuida sin un permiso de uso, no debes hacerlo porque te verías en problemas. A eso se refiere la parte que mencionas.

Comment: Si tienes un área legal que te interprete esa parte será bueno; creo "ncrustar" no se limita a que en tu instalador la incluyas; el simple hecho de usarla ya estas "incrustandola". De cada componente debes leer la licencia; aún cuando veas "gratuito" puede tener consideraciones como "gratis": para ambientes de desarrollo y/o pruebas pero no para productivos; sin fines lucrativos, intranets... La facilidad y control de implementar algo mediante Visual Studio no otorga ningún derecho sobre licencia de terceros.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, entonces no existe ningun problema ya que las fuentes permiten todo eso, me he pasado bastante tiempo buscando fonts para uso comercial y redistribución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes distribuir las fuentes de terceros en tu software mientras tengan algun tipo de licencia de distribución, siempre y cuando incluyas los términos y licencia de distribución incluida en las licencias de las fuentes lo cual cubre el punto (ii) la parte de reclamaciones de ley, los puntos que menciona la clausula solo aplican para Alemania Y Austria:

> c.    Alemania y Austria. 
>   (i)   Garantía. El software funcionará
>   esencialmente como se describe en la documentación de Microsoft que lo
>   acompaña. Sin embargo, Microsoft no otorga garantía contractual en
>   relación con el software. 
>   (ii)  Limitación de responsabilidad. En caso
>   de comportamiento intencional, negligencia grave, reclamaciones
>   basadas en la Ley de Responsabilidad por Productos, así como en caso
>   de muerte, daños corporales o lesiones físicas, Microsoft es
>   responsable conforme a la legislación.

y como lo mencionas:

> por las licencias de las fonts no hay que preocuparse, permiten uso
>   comercial y redistribución

Las fuentes ya tienen cubierto ese aspecto legal

Comment: Gracias por responder tan claro a mi pregunta, ya entiendo que no existe ningún problema. Que tengas un buen día.

Comment: @Tamara si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema no dudes en aceptarla en el check debajo de la puntuacion, eso ayuda al sitio y a otras personas. saludos